# Blend 20+ sc-domain properties into one data source?

Tags: google-search-console, google-data-studio

Pretty much same question as this [Fetch/Combine/Blend multiple Google Search Console different sc-domains](https://support.google.com/looker-studio/thread/88532051/fetch-combine-blend-multiple-google-search-console-different-sc-domains?hl=en) (unanswered).

I have 20+ regional domains in Search Console. I added all of them as data sources. Now I want to see, lets say, *Site CTR* or *Average Position* for all domains together on one chart. With the built-in tools right now I can place 20 individual charts next to each other, but that's much less helpful visually.

I tried to create a Blend, but it allows only 5 tables only. And even if I merge my top-5 countries into one Blend, the line chart forces me to choose one property as a dimension; I can't have all 5 properties on the same chart.

Thought about doing it through Google Sheets, but that would have to be manual for every domain. Furthermore, according to [Exporting Search Console data to spreadsheets](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wLVrHKursgU) there's a limit of 1000 rows per export.

I'm sure I'm missing something. How do I have all of my properties on one chart?